# z-index issue in ie

Tags: css, z-index

i know this issue is well documented but i cant find a working solution from what ive been reading. I have a pretty large site and i want a div to sit ontop of everything else on the site. now ive tried giving the div `"position:absolute; z-index:99999;"`, this will work in everything apart from ie. How can i do this in ie?

Comment: Have you already tried all the solutions given to similar questions on SO? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=z-index+IE+issue

Comment: @phil crowe: Tell us all of the things you've tried and already determined *not* to work. It's way easier for all of us than starting from the beginning.

Comment: so the common solution i find is this ul { position:absolute; z-index:1000; }
ul li { position:relative; } 

basically make the parent have a higher z-index than the element you want to appear on top. but i just want one div to sit over everything, the only parent to this div is the body tag.

Comment: ive also tried it the other way round. this didnt work either

Comment: can you give us alive example of your webpage?

Comment: even though ive posted a solution i still think id rather find an alternative. the site does load slightly slower now. I cant provide a link due to the nature of the site ;o

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
position: fixed; z-index: 9999;
```

This will make the div to appear on top of the others. (and follow as you scroll down)

Comment: this doesnt make the div appear above the others. just makes the div move with the screen but its still behind everything else.

Comment: this should work... have you tried to add z-index: 0; to body?

Answer (score 0):

so i tried this jquery script i found

```
$(function () {
    var zIndexNumber = 1000;
   $('div').each(function () {


        $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
        zIndexNumber -= 10;
    });
});
```

i added another wrapper around it to check if the broswer is ie before hand. this seems to fix the issue but does mean pages are slower loading in ie as every div is being treated. when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't what should happen.  Without seeing the HTML & CSS,  it's difficult to identify why.  Some standard debugging techniques...

Setting the z-index to a very high number should render that element in front of everything else**.  If it's not being rendered in front,  then something is setting the z-index of the other elements to something higher.  This could be set in CSS or by script.  The quick check is to turn off scripting. To investigate this,  use firebug to find the z-index of the element in front.  To find it,  edit any scripts, even minified ones, and simply search for "z-index".

It sounds like a quick "back to basics" re-examination of the problem may yeild the cause.

Normally one would use low z-index numbers - 2 is higher than 1,  why use more?!?  Some plug-in developers have been known to use stupidly high z-index numbers.

.

** IE 6 has a well-known bug where replaced form elements (e.g. select) will 'shine' through.  The fix is to put an iframe in front of it.